# GCC C++ Name mangling reference

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, name-mangling

Looking around, I see mostly questions about demangling C++ symbols rather than how to mangle them. Yes, one could invoke `g++`, using the `-S` option, on some dummy code containing the symbols to be mangled, and then examine the resulting assembly, but I haven't been able to find a good reference or specification on GCC's name mangling. The closest thing I could find was at http://www.int0x80.gr/papers/name_mangling.pdf, but it doesn't seem to cover things like how names template instantiations are mangled or why `_Z3fooIN3BarEE3FooIXT_EEv` would translate into `Foo<Bar> foo<Bar>()` (though I can kind of see how, but what the hell is `IXT_EE`? Why is there no `N` after the `_Z` in this one? What's that even mean?).

Comment: Look up the Itanium ABI for C++, which GCC uses.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Is there a standalone implementation of mangling / demangling using the Itanium ABI? Or is it only implemented within compilers?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Quote from [source code of gcc's implementation of name mangling](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/mangle.cc):

> This file implements mangling of C++ names according to the IA64 C++
> ABI specification.

And here is the rules from this specification:
https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling

Comment: Is there some reference implementation of these rules?